# Exploring json null and "" and hibernate null and "" and MySql/Postgres null and "". Have a good method?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hibernate

Different potential solutions in bold throughout but I am looking for more ideas...

- Json supports null and ""
- Java supports null and "" and null = null
- MySQL supports null and "" but null != null in WHERE clause (c.col = :variable won't match)

We are in healthcare which has very very sparse matrices.  lots of nulls or "" depending on how you look at the problem.  To make things worse, hibernate's query.setParameter("variable", null) won't throw an exception and silently returns 0 rows so developers think their stuff is working especially when missing a specific test case which happens all the time.

In an ideal world, MySQL for us would support null = null in the WHERE clause and John null Smith would be a unique row if I had a constraint on first, middle, last name.  Instead, you can get John null Smith many many times.  You cannot however had John "" Smith many times so at least that is good.

Sooooo, we could go to a method of

- **Make all columns nullable=false and always insert ""**

This leads to the issue of Jackson sending null OR not sending some fields in at all which currently map to null (non-existence of a field AND null both map to null).  This is fixable in that you can default constructor every Jackson bean's String fields to "".  We can also modify the ObjectMapper so all Strings come in as "" always so no developer mistakes would be made.

If we go the route of nullable=false, we then lose the original database constraints that we had and were using in that clientId was nullable=false and this would fail when json came in and was missing clientId since jackson would produce a bean with clientId=null and that would be set on the database violating the constraint.  We had about 30% of our fields nullable=false and those checks basically no longer help us since all values coming in are always "" now instead :(.  ie. a real nightmare of a choice to not catch data corruption.  I guess I mean, data corruption will now be more likely since we can't get mysql to be able to do WHERE null = null the way 'we want'(well, and I guess tons of others expect as well reading through many SO posts so far).

The other way to go is have

- **WHERE coerce(c.col, "--unknown--") = coerce(:variable, "--unknown--)"**

BUT the unique constraint still is not working in that case in that John null Smith has too many rows when there should be 1.  In postgres, this is solvable with a special unique constraint with WHERE clause using coerce, but then the index is not performant at all since it has functions....nightmare hit yet again.

I am wondering what others currently do in the java world OR world of languages where null is a thing?  This is not I want opinions but more I want different ways people have solve the problem.

EDIT: We could also use is null or is not null HOWEVER this became very very unwieldy very fast.  Again, we are healthcare with very sparse matrics and the SQL queries became very very nasty since we do this on 6 attributes or so and have to check do we need to switch from c.col=variable to c.col is null based on the value of variable for each one.  All the examples of the HQL on the web are well, quite a bit more code resulting in less maintainable code.  Not only that, this still doesn't solve the constraint issue of John null Smith existing multiple times.

Comment: in mysql you use column IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

Comment: @nbk Added an EDIT section to make why is null is a bit of a PITA as well as how that doesn't solve the John null Smith issue at all, but thanks for reading and   taking a look!!!